# Having a complier issue as well as declaration of Cursor issue?

Tags: sql, oracle, database-cursor

So I am creating a procedure for my project. It said the declaration of cursor is incomplete which led to a statement being ignored. Due to that my T_ROW is invalid and then it finally gave me a compiler log issue. Im fairly new to SQL Oracle database im trying to fix it.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE T(Trip_ID in NUMBER) IS
CURSOR Trips_CURSOR IS SELECT * FROM TRIPS
where TRIPS_ID = T_INFO;
T_ROW Trips_CURSOR%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The ID of this trip is ' || T_INFO);
 FOR T_ROW IN Trips_CURSOR LOOP
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The Date of the trip is ' || T_ROW.DATE_OF_TRIP);
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The Destination town of the Trip ' || T_ROW.Destination_Town);
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The Source town is  ' || T_ROW.Source_Town);

END LOOP;
END;
```

Here is a screenshot of my code as well:
[Image of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKYRk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your screenshot, your `TRIPS` table has the columns `TRIPS_ID`, `DATE_OF_TRIP`, `DESTINATION_TOWN` and `SOURCE_TOWN`. However, you do not have a `T_INFO` column and your parameter is not called `T_INFO` so you have probably given the parameter the wrong name:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE T(
  T_INFO in TRIPS.TRIPS_ID%TYPE
)
IS
  CURSOR Trips_CURSOR IS
   SELECT *
   FROM   TRIPS
   WHERE  TRIPS_ID = T_INFO;

  T_ROW Trips_CURSOR%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The ID of this trip is ' || T_INFO);
 FOR T_ROW IN Trips_CURSOR LOOP
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The Date of the trip is ' || T_ROW.DATE_OF_TRIP);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The Destination town of the Trip ' || T_ROW.Destination_Town);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The Source town is  ' || T_ROW.Source_Town);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d95301092953551140bf451f7844d4d0)*